# JUCE image buttons without embedding files

Tags: c++, xcode, juce

Is there anyway to just include a file from a relative path using JUCE?  Between graphics, up and down button states, I have about 40 images and trying to create them through the ProJucer causes thousands of lines (over 20,00 in this particular situation) to be generated and embedded in my GUI component.  This is causing huge performance issues in Xcode for me.  Is it possible to just include the files via relative path and save all that embedded code?  The .cpp is so large even GitHub says they are too large to display. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you just mean that you want to ship a directory of image files with your app and populate your image buttons at runtime from those files?

Comment: @bgporter - I suppose so.  All I know is adding images into the ProJucer and letting it embed them is causing my sessions to become so large that Xcode can't handle it (more accurately, my comp, since I'm running it on a small MacBook Air, maybe it's time to upgrade.  I'm still new to JUCE, the ProJucer, and GUI development in general, so Idk if this is normal or not.  Is it normal for sessions with lots of images to have thousands of lines of embedded code just for images?  I don't see why Xcode is slowing down so much either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use embedded images in your project, but *not* have them taking up space inside each component's `.cpp` file as generated by the Projucer, do this instead:

- Add the image files to the Projucer project itself.

  [image: (images added to Projucer)]

When you save the Projucer project, the image data will be added to your project's `BinaryData.h/cpp` file that's located in the `JuceLibraryCode` directory.

- When you want to create the ImageButton, instead of selecting 'create a new image resource' (which would put the binary data into your component's source directly), select the BinaryData resource that you created above:

[image: select the image resource]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try this when I get home from class and accept the answer.

Comment: Quick question, out of either embedding the images into the source code or including them via the method you described, which method tends to be used more in the developing field?  I'm new to GUI development so I'm not sure which is more "socially acceptable."  All I know is embedding is causing massive performance issues on my end.  Any cons to using this method?

Comment: Well, this is in the source code, it's just putting the images into a different file. And among JUCE developers, I think you'd find people disagreeing a lot on the topic. Using the BinaryData approach here is how Jules thinks it should be done, but you'll also see people avoid using the Projucer at all costs and instead loading binary files from the drive at runtime.

Comment: I avoid coding in the ProJucer at all costs as well.  I just use it for the GUI arrangement.  Thank you for your help.  I'm about to try your solution.

Comment: Ahh shoot, now I can't see the buttons.  I figured there was going to be a drawback.  Very strange that the image can be previewed using this method.

Comment: Pretty sure that you need the paid version of the Projucer to get the live-build capabilities.

Comment: It builds live views when allowing the images to be stored on the main component, just not this method.